# Load TensorFlow embedding model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am following the reference from the following page:

https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4

In the code the model is loaded from the internet with the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

embed = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4")
```

I would like to be able to load a model I have saved in my local directory

For example:

```
embed = hub.Module('data\models\universal-sentence-encoder_4.tar.gz')
```

This code returns the following error

```
RuntimeError: Missing implementation that supports: loader
```

How can this be done?

Comment: It might be a download issue, have you tried [this solution](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/212#issuecomment-451923229) ?

Answer (score 3):

The Issue was that the file was not unzipped.

After unzipping, the directory path was pointed to the unzip content location, with no file name specified.

Also the `Module` method was changed to `load`

the code below works, assuming the unzipped embedding model .pb file and accompanying folders are located in the specified directory.

```
embed = hub.load('data\models\')
```